# See if a string begins with whitespace in Java

Tags: java, whitespace

I know that trim removes whitespace from the beginning and end of a string, but I wanted to check if the first character of a string is a whitespace. I've tried what seems about everything, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I'd appreciate it if regular expressions were not used.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
if (Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(0))) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Just be sure to check that the string isn't empty.

Comment: @EboMike: Indeed, I just assumed that the OP can handle that.

Comment: Also note that Character#isWhitespace is not 100% compatible with String#trim. One detects Unicode whitespace, one handles ASCII control characters. You can use Commons Lang StringUtils#strip for a more sane version of trim.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(0))) //...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void yourMethod(String string) {
    if (isLengthGreaterThanZero(string) && isFirstCharacterWhiteSpace(string)) {
        ...
    }
}

private boolean isFirstCharacterWhiteSpace(String string) {
    char firstCharacter = string.charAt(0);
    return Character.isWhitespace(firstCharacter);
}

private boolean isLengthGreaterThanZero(String string) {
    return string != null && string.length() > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"string".startsWith(" ")
```

Comment: But this would miss strings that start with other whitespace, like `"\t\r\n\v\f"`...